# QLPreviewController - Play video iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm using QLPreviewController to preview all kind of documents as well as video files. While trying to open a video file using that, it works fine with iOS 7 whereas with iOS 6, video playback controls are not showing up, only empty toolbar getting shown. Hence, unable to play a video in iOS 6.

This is the code which i'm using..

```
QLPreviewController *previewController=[[QLPreviewController alloc]init];
previewController.delegate=self;
previewController.dataSource=self;
[self addChildViewController:previewController];
previewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 46, 768, 905);
previewController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:previewController.view];
```

Screenshots with iOS 6 & iOS 7

[image] [image]